# Criar pacote nuget a partir de uma aplicação Web API REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, nuget

Eu tenho um serviço WEB API REST em ASP.NET CORE 2.0 vários projetos(camadas) nele. Porém, por forças maiores, não poderá ser usado como serviço.

Foi então sugerido criar um pacote nuget para este WEB API. Eu nunca criei um pacote nuget e tenho visto exemplos na internet de projetos simples sendo usados como pacote nuget e não uma WEB API REST. A dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu posso gerar um pacote nuget de minha aplicação WEB API REST?

--

** **Edit**

--

**Força maior** => Os stackeholders receosos

**Tipo de Aplicação** => Log de Auditoria (para várias outras aplicações)

**Situação**

As aplicações não poderão realizar nada sem fazer log antes e os stackeholders estão receosos de que, por ventura, esta API venha a parar de funcionar por algum motivo, e todas as aplicações que consumiam este serviço parem de funcionar.

--

**Arquitetura da Aplicação**

- Controller
- Application
- Domain
- Repository
- etc...

1º) Eu precisaria mudar a Arquitetura?

2º) Caso seja possível usar essa API como pacote nuget, eu o utilizaria como se fosse um serviço? Por exemplo tenho a rota GET: http://localhost/api/logs. Eu usaria essas rotas dos Controllers? Ou eu acessaria os recursos da API de outra forma?

- Aqui está o repositório deste meu projeto: https://github.com/LeoFelipe/AuditLog

Comment: Poderia esclarecer quais são as forças maiores?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, nada impede que você implemente um pacote NuGet que quando invocado prepara *endpoints* WebAPI.

Este cenário pode ser útil quando você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação web compatível com *endpoints* REST.

É o caso por exemplo da seguinte biblioteca:

https://github.com/bucknellu/Nyan

Note que um dos módulos (https://github.com/bucknellu/Nyan/tree/master/Modules/Web/REST) tem como objetivo oferecer funcionalidades como *endpoints* WebAPI.

Incidentemente este módulo está também disponível como um pacote NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nyan.Modules.Web.REST/

Respondendo, então, à suas perguntas:

> 1º) Eu precisaria mudar a Arquitetura?

**Não.** Ela pode ser mantida da mesma maneira. A única coisa que você precisa guarantir é que os *API controllers* do pacote NuGet sejam carregados e disponibilizados da mesma maneira.

> 2º) Caso seja possível usar essa API como pacote nuget, eu o utilizaria como se fosse um serviço? Por exemplo tenho a rota GET: http://localhost/api/logs. Eu usaria essas rotas dos Controllers? Ou eu acessaria os recursos da API de outra forma?

Sim. A única diferença entre os controllers da sua aplicação e os do(s) pacote(s) NuGet é o assembly onde eles estão localizados.

Quando você incorpora um pacote à sua aplicação, o que você está realmente fazendo é realizando o *download* de um conjunto de *assemblies* que serão referenciados pelo seu projeto.

Quando executada sua aplicação web será disponibilizada sob uma URL onde serão servidos todos os *endpoints* - tanto os da sua aplicação *quanto os presentes em assemblies referenciados*.

Assim, você poderá continuar a utilizar URLs relativas locais para acessar os endpoints (`api/logs`, por exemplo.)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, então eu me comunicaria com este pacote nuget do mesmo modo que eu faria enquanto serviço? Por exemplo via GET: api/locations, para resgatar as localizações? Irei editar e exemplificar melhor na minha pergunta.

Comment: @LeoFelipe Eu expandi a resposta para cobrir o seu caso de uso.